# Why is my html form not sending its data to my php file?

Tags: php, html

i am trying to send data from a form in html but it seems that the data from the form is not sent to the php side as all the variable are appearing undefined.it was working before but for some reason it broke and no longer sends data to my database.

```
 <form action="connect.php" method="post">
              <label class="labe"><h5>Name:</h5></label>
              <input class="txtbx" type="text" name="cust_name" placeholder="enter your name here" required>
              <div class="box1">
                <div class="box2">
                <label class="labe"><h3>department:</h3></label>
                <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="dept" value="department1" required>department1</label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name="dept" value="department2">department2</label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name="dept" value="department3">department3</label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name="dept" value="department4">department4</label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name="dept" value="department5">department5</label>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="satifaction_box">
                <div class="box2">
                  <h3 class="polo">Rate your satifaction with:</h3>
                <div class="box3">
                <label class="labe"><h3>facilities:</h3></label>
                <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="facilities" value="good" required>good
                  <label><input type="radio" name="facilities" value="neutral">neutral
                  <label> <input type="radio" name="facilities" value="bad">bad<br>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
                <div class="box3">
                 <label class="labe"><h3>faculty:</h3></label>
                 <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="faculty" value="good" required>good
                  <label> <input type="radio" name="faculty" value="neutral">neutral
                  <label><input type="radio" name="faculty" value="bad">bad<br>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="box3">
                 <label class="labe"><h3>extracurricular:</h3></label>
                 <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="good" required>good
                  <label><input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="neutral">neutral
                  <label><input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="bad">bad<br>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="box3">
                 <label class="labe"><h3>safety:</h3></label>
                 <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="safety" value="good" required>good
                  <label><input type="radio" name="safety" value="neutral">neutral
                  <label><input type="radio" name="safety" value="bad">bad<br>  
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="box3">
                 <label class="labe"><h3>curricullum:</h3></label>
                 <div class="opt">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="good" required>good
                  <label><input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="neutral">neutral
                  <label><input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="bad">bad<br>
                </div>
                 </div>

                </div>
               </div>
               <div class="comment">
                <input class="txtbx" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comment here" >
               </div>
               <button type="submit">Submit</button>

              </form>
```

here is the php file

```
<?php
if (isset ($cust_name)  || ($dept) || ($facilities) ||($faculty) || ($safety) || ($ciricullum) || ($comment)){
$cust_name = $_post['cust_name'];
$dept= $_post['dept'];
$facilities= $_post['facilities'];
$faculty= $_post['faculty'];
$extraciricular= $_post['extraciricular'];
$safety= $_post['safety'];
$ciricullum= $_post['ciricullum'];
$comment= $_post['comment'];

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','your_password','your_password','suveyres');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die('connection failed:'.$conn->connect_error);
}
else{ 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into surveyresult(cust_name,dept,facilities,faculty,extraciricular,safety,ciricullum,comment) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$cust_name,$dept,$facilities,$faculty,$extraciricular,safety,ciricullum,comment);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "thanks for your feedback";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
}

else{
    echo "none of the form data has reached the php file";
}

?>
```

i have tried changing the address and adding a check with isset but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: `isset ($cust_name)` - where does `$cust_name` come from? The same for the other variables - presumably you mean `$_POST['cust_name']`? Also, `isset` **will** take multiple arguments but **not** using the `OR` argument to separate them

Comment: `label` elements are not intended to hold arbitrary pieces of HTML content - they are used with `input` elements of some sort and either use `for=ID` type syntax to relate the label to the input **or** the input element is wholly contained within the label

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you were facing was because of the (mis)use of `isset` and the undeclared variables.

`isset` will accept multiple arguments and will return false if any of those arguments fails the test. You supply a comma separated list of variables to test - you do not use `OR` between the variables.

The `isset` test elow explicitly tests that each required form element appears in the POST array and proceeds to build the placeholder string accordingly. It passes the arguments to the `bind_param` method using the splat operator for convenience.

```
<?php

    $rows=false;
    
    if( isset(
        $_POST['cust_name'],
        $_POST['dept'],
        $_POST['facilities'],
        $_POST['faculty'],
        $_POST['extraciricular'],
        $_POST['safety'],
        $_POST['ciricullum'],
        $_POST['comment']
    )){

        $args=array(
            $_POST['cust_name'],
            $_POST['dept'],
            $_POST['facilities'],
            $_POST['faculty'],
            $_POST['extraciricular'],
            $_POST['safety'],
            $_POST['ciricullum'],
            $_POST['comment']
        );
        
        $types=str_repeat('s',count( $args ) );
        
        $sql='INSERT INTO `surveyresult` 
                ( `cust_name`, `dept`, `facilities`, `faculty`, `extraciricular`, `safety`, `ciricullum`, `comment`) 
                    VALUES 
                ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';


        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','your_password','your_password','suveyres');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$args );
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
    }
    
    # if $rows is no longer false the insert succeeded.

?>
```

---

Given a very basic table schema for `surveyresult`, as below:

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cust_name      | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| dept           | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| facilities     | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| faculty        | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| extraciricular | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| safety         | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| ciricullum     | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| comment        | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And an "All in one page" example script featuring essentially the same HTML form but reduced to the bare-bones and with radio buttons pre-checked.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $rows=false;
    $status='Commiserations';
    

    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( isset(
            $_POST['cust_name'],
            $_POST['dept'],
            $_POST['facilities'],
            $_POST['faculty'],
            $_POST['extraciricular'],
            $_POST['safety'],
            $_POST['ciricullum'],
            $_POST['comment']
        )){

            $args=array(
                $_POST['cust_name'],
                $_POST['dept'],
                $_POST['facilities'],
                $_POST['faculty'],
                $_POST['extraciricular'],
                $_POST['safety'],
                $_POST['ciricullum'],
                $_POST['comment']
            );
            
            $types=str_repeat('s',count( $args ) );
            
            $sql='INSERT INTO `surveyresult` 
                    ( `cust_name`, `dept`, `facilities`, `faculty`, `extraciricular`, `safety`, `ciricullum`, `comment`) 
                        VALUES 
                    ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';
                    
                    
            /*
            $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','your_password','your_password','suveyres');
            */  

            
            $dbport     =   3306;
            $dbhost     =   'localhost';
            $dbuser     =   'xxx';
            $dbpwd      =   'xxx';
            $dbname     =   'xxx';
            
            mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
            $conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname, $dbport );
            
            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$args );
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            
            
            $status='Congratulations!';
            
        }
        
        # if $rows is no longer false the insert succeeded.
        exit( sprintf('Rows:%s Status:%s', $rows, $status ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="cust_name" placeholder="enter your name here" required />
            
            <input type="radio" name="dept" value="department1" checked />department1
            <input type="radio" name="dept" value="department2" />department2
            <input type="radio" name="dept" value="department3" />department3
            <input type="radio" name="dept" value="department4" />department4
            <input type="radio" name="dept" value="department5" />department5
            
            <input type="radio" name="facilities" value="good" checked required />good 
            <input type="radio" name="facilities" value="neutral" />neutral 
            <input type="radio" name="facilities" value="bad" />bad 
            
            <input type="radio" name="faculty" value="good" checked required />good 
            <input type="radio" name="faculty" value="neutral" />neutral 
            <input type="radio" name="faculty" value="bad" />bad 
            
            <input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="good" checked required />good 
            <input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="neutral" />neutral 
            <input type="radio" name="extraciricular" value="bad" />bad 
            
            <input type="radio" name="safety" value="good" checked required />good 
            <input type="radio" name="safety" value="neutral" />neutral 
            <input type="radio" name="safety" value="bad" />bad 
            
            <input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="good" checked required />good 
            <input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="neutral" />neutral 
            <input type="radio" name="ciricullum" value="bad" />bad 
            
            <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comment here" />
            
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<!--

    ???????????????????????????????????
    extraciricular  ->  extracurricular
    ciricullum      ->  curriculum

-->
```

And after completing the html form and populating the db you can see:

```
mysql> select * from `surveyresult`;
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+------------+-------------+
| id | cust_name | dept        | facilities | faculty | extraciricular | safety | ciricullum | comment     |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | geronimo  | department1 | good       | good    | good           | good   | good       | Hello World |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The example runs perfectly well in test and results are immediately populated to db.The PHP has not really changed from the original so it's not clear why you were finding variables were not set. That aside, I hope this helps resolve your issue.

Comment: it says 

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli::__construct(): Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kiosk\connect.php:35 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\kiosk\connect.php(35): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'your_password', 'suveyres') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kiosk\connect.php on line 35

Comment: @killerqueen well that's a problem with your database connection code, which is nothing to do with what is written here. Replace the string port number value with an integer, as the error message says, and try again. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php - check which value goes where in the argument list.

Comment: tried it and looks like they are not set for some reason .i wrote an else statement if it is not set and it showed that the parameters are not set

Comment: One thing to note perhaps - your sql is adding strings to the `surveyresult` table where it really should be adding integers that are keys to other tables. [Perhaps investigate "Database Normalisation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)